# mergeDebugResources FAILED, dot is not a valid file-based resource name character

Tags: android, naming-conventions, android-resources

Is it ok to name different resolution resource files like this:

```
...\src\main\res\drawable\about.48.png  
...\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\about.64.png  
...\src\main\res\drawable-xhdpi\about.128.png
```

Previously my app used to compile just fine, but now I am getting this error:

```
mergeDebugResources FAILED      
Error: '.' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't name your res file to like 'about.64.png',name can't contain a dot,
You just need to rename them to about.png.